# fread read error "Expected sep (' ') but.."

Tags: r, data.table

`fread` {data.table} is having difficulty with a tab-separated file that features lines that are partially quoted. I can't find a workaround because it handles quotes automatically (hence no `quote` argument as there is for `read.csv`).  This illustrates:

```
str1 = 'L1\tsome\tunquoted\tstuff\nL2\tsome\t"half" quoted\tstuff\nL3\tthis\t"should work"\tok thought'
str2 = gsub('"', '', str1)

fread(str2, sep='\t', header=F, skip=0L)
#    V1   V2          V3         V4
# 1: L1 some    unquoted      stuff
# 2: L2 some half quoted      stuff
# 3: L3 this should work ok thought
fread(str1, sep='\t', header=F, skip=0L)
# Error in fread(str1, sep = "\t", header = F, skip = 0L) : 
#   Expected sep (' ') but '
# ' ends field 3 on line 1 when detecting types: L2 some    "half" quoted   stuff
```

Is there any way to resolve this, save for for doing a find/replace on the original file?

Comment: How many columns do you want in the result?

Comment: Hi Richard.  Well it's 4 columns in this example

Comment: This works perfectly fine with the development version on GitHub. I'm voting to close this as "not reproducible"

Comment: @RichardScriven Why is that? I think this bug is documnented in the [README.md](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table)

Comment: I was joking (a bit).  Is not knowing about a non-distributed dev-version of a function grounds for closing though?

Comment: Yes, because if a bug was fixed aleady, what's the point to try re fixing it again? I didn't critisize/down-vote, I was just stating a fact.

Comment: @DavidArenburg, I think `fread(str1, sep='\t', header=F, skip=0L)` still errors?

Comment: @Arun, Yes, I didn't see the first line, I thought `fread(str2, sep='\t', header=F, skip=0L)` was returning the error.

Comment: As @DavidArenburg has mentioned, it'd be nice if you could post a bug report on the project page so that we don't miss it. Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1079

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about `stringi` instead?  Pretty simple to figure out, and very efficient.  There is also a function `stri_read_lines()`, for reading/splitting lines from file.

```
library(stringi)

as.data.frame(stri_split_fixed(stri_split_lines1(str1), "\t", simplify = TRUE))
#   V1   V2            V3         V4
# 1 L1 some      unquoted      stuff
# 2 L2 some "half" quoted      stuff
# 3 L3 this "should work" ok thought
```

If you need convincing that this is a more efficient method than `read.*()`, have a look at the timings for the above method when applied to a flattened string that parses to 30k rows. You could also speed it up even more by adjusting the arguments in `as.data.frame()`.  For this example, the `stringi` method is roughly twice as fast as `read.table()`.

```
str1 <- "L1\tsome\tunquoted\tstuff\nL2\tsome\t\"half\" quoted\tstuff\nL3\tthis\t\"should work\"\tok thought"

library(stringi)
library(microbenchmark)

write(stri_flatten(rep(str1, 1e5), collapse = "\n"))
file.info("data")[1]
#         size
# data 8400000

microbenchmark(
    stringi = {
        mat <- stri_split_fixed(stri_read_lines("data"), "\t", simplify = TRUE)
        out <- as.data.frame(mat)
    },
    read.table = {
        out2 <- read.table("data", sep = "\t", quote = "\n")
    },
    times = 3L,
    unit = "relative"
)

# Unit: relative
#        expr      min       lq     mean   median      uq      max neval cld
#     stringi 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.00000 1.000000     3  a 
#  read.table 2.074071 2.111722 1.997857 2.148897 1.96356 1.808365     3   b

identical(out, out2)
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Cheers I'll try it  my big file and revert

Comment: @eddi - I added timings.  Still waiting for `read.csv()` to finish though. ;-)

Comment: @David  - I use 1.9.5 and `fread()` is not working, as op mentions

Comment: `fread(str2, sep='\t', header=F, skip=0L)` doesn't work for you?

Comment: @david-arenburg it's `str1` that's the problem

Comment: I get that, but question is if `fread(gsub('"', '', str1, fixed = TRUE), sep='\t', header=F, skip=0L)` would still be faster than the `stringi` version.

Comment: @geotheory - Am I  mistaken, or did you want to read in the file without altering it *i.e. with half quotes)?

Comment: With the quotes. I gave the example without to prove the cause :)

Comment: Hmm, it seems like I completely misunderstood the question (as `fread(str1, sep='\t', header=F, skip=0L)` was blended within the output before Aruns edit). Then this is a nice solution Richard (+1). Though @geotheory you probably should post these kind of questions on GitHub as bug/FR in the first place.

Comment: Thanks @David.  I wasn't trying to say `stringi` is better than using `fread()`, btw. You know I like me some data table

Comment: Yes it probably should've gone in github.  I've posted it https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1079

Comment: @richard-scriven useful thanks. Not quite the same leagues as "fread for speed" but I'll tick off til a `data.table` solution becomes available :)