# data.table - fread() importing a file with double quotes

Tags: r, data.table

How do I import a file that contains double quotes (i.e. "").

For example:
"test.tab"

```
nam1    nam2    nam3
A   test    1
B   test2   2
C   "This" is test3 3
D   test4   4
E   This is "test5" 5

library(data.table)
test1 <- fread("test.tab")
```

This does not yield what I want.

I can get the correct output by using `read.table` with `quote = ""`.

```
test2 <- read.table(file = "test.tab", sep = "\t", header = TRUE, quote = "")
```

Do we have `quote = ""` equivalent in `fread`?

Thanks,

Comment: No. See [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/568)

Comment: And [this duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28970082/fread-read-error-expected-sep-but/28971031)

Comment: @DavidArenburg: As per your link https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/568 "quote" should have been implemented but still data.table vignette under fread command https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/data.table.pdf or in git https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.9.6/topics/fread? Am I missing something?

Comment: @RichScriven: please fill in if you are updated

Comment: @abhiieor I'm not sure if it was already implemented in v1.9.6, but it does exist in v1.9.7 (I haven't tested it though)

Comment: @abhiieor I suggest you read the docs and see when this was introduced.

Comment: for those who happen to see this post later, `quote` argument in `fread()` is coming in data.table 1.9.7